# How to make subcolumns in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

How do i make subcolums un select sql like this

```
       Column1              |  Column2           |      Column3        |
       | cat1 | cat2 | cat3 | cat1 | cat2 | cat3 | cat1 | cat2 | cat3  |
row1   |  2   |  3   |  1   |   1  |   2  |   0  |   2  |  1   |   0   |
row2   |  7   |  5   |  7   |   2  |   4  |   1  |   0  |  1   |   2   |
row3   |  3   |  0   |  3   |   3  |   8  |   0  |   2  |  0   |   2   |
```

Comment: You can't.  SQL rows have only one column name.

Comment: As @GordonLinoff said, you can't.  Perhaps if you explained what you think you are trying to achieve . . . .

Comment: I am trying to make an excel file with subcolumns, wich was selected from db.can i do it programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done programmatically from Excel, if not in SQL per se. I recommend exporting the columns in some manner that encodes both header levels in the column names and then using an Excel macro/VBA script to format them as you want.

For instance, you could make the columns "Column1-cat1", "cat2", ... and then within Excel you can split compound names, put them above the header, and merge with empty cells to the right.